# React: adding className to single element of mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that maps images from an `items` array.  Upon clicking any item, I am calling `addFavorite`, which is passed in from the parent.
I am trying to find a way to also have a className added to *only* the specific image(s) I click on.  Any approach I've tried adds the class to all the mapped out elements upon onClick.

```
var classNames = require('classnames');


class Results extends Component {

  render() {
    let items = this.props.items

    var resultClass = classNames({
      'result': true,
    });

    return (
      <div className="resultst" key="results">
        {items.map(item => 
            <div className = {resultClass} 
                 key={item.id} 
                 onClick= {() => { 
                    this.props.addFavorite(item) 
                 }
                }>
                <img alt= "" src={item.images.downsized.url} />
            </div>
        )} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your parent component as well? A good solution might be to have a `isFavorite` field on your items, and then you can just add the class to the favorite items: `<div className={resultClass + (item.isFavorite ? ' favoriteClass' : '')} ...`

Comment: thanks.  the items are coming back from API so i'd rather not add fields to the existing data structure of the returned JSON .. if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate `favorites` array in your parent component that you store all the favorite items in, and send that to your child component and see if the item is included in the `favorites` array:

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ id: 1, text: "item 1" }, { id: 2, text: "item 2" }],
    favorites: []
  };

  addFavorite = item => {
    const { items, favorites } = this.state;
    const copyFavorites = [...favorites];

    if (!favorites.some(favorite => favorite.id === item.id)) {
      copyFavorites.push(item);
      this.setState({ favorites: copyFavorites });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { items, favorites } = this.state;
    const { addFavorite } = this;

    return (
      <div>
        <Results
          items={items}
          favorites={favorites}
          addFavorite={addFavorite}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Results extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items, favorites, addFavorite } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            onClick={() => {
              addFavorite(item);
            }}
          >
            {favorites.includes(item) && 'Favorite: '}
            {item.text}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```